# How to use unicode-math with beamer and lualatex?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, latin-modern

According to a recent article in "Die TeXnische Komödie", this should be the way to get Latin Modern Math to work with lualatex and the latest TeXLive 2011:

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \ifLuaTeX
    \usepackage{luatextra}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}
    \usepackage{unicode-math} 
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
  \fi
\fi
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{(#1, #2)}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Speaker's Name}{About Our Next Speaker}
\LaTeX\ is good at typesetting mathematical formulas
like
       \( x-3y + z = 7 \) 
or
       \( a_{1} > x^{2n} + y^{2n} > x' \)
or  
       \( \ip{A}{B} = \sum_{i} a_{i} b_{i} \).
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It works (at least according to `pdffonts`), but unicode-math
complains:

```
* unicode-math warning: "disable-beamer"
* 
* Disabling beamer's math setup.
* Please load beamer with the [professionalfonts] class option.
```

And this message is repeated a dozen times:

```
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available
* for font 'LatinModernMath',
* with script 'Math', and language 'Default'.
```

What's wrong with my setup?

**EDIT:**
The fontspec warnings go away if one removes the `Numbers=OldStyle` from the `\defaultfontfeatures`.

**EDIT2:**
I removed the `ifxetex` package and changed the `\ifluatex` to `\ifLuaTeX`.

Comment: No idea about the first message, but since you are not loading any text fonts with fontspec, the `\defaultfontfeatures` line makes no sense, you neither need (or want) TeX quote ligatures nor old style numbers in math mode.

Comment: also, don't directly load `luatextra`, it is a low-level package that is for other packages to load, you don't need to load it in your document.

Comment: Beamer change math alphabets unless it detects certain packages. Load it with professionalfonts option prevent this. You should read the manual.

Comment: @Yan: If you look at the example given you will see that Martin *does* load it with the `professionalfonts` option.  Actually the class option is `professionalfont` and is now obsolete.  The manual is also slightly confusing on this issue since on p19 it refers to a class option whereas on p193 to a font theme.  Also, `unicode-math`s warning adds to the confusion by getting the class option wrong.  Finally, please do not swear, not even in abbreviations.

Comment: Martin: Can you clarify the actual problem here.  Is it just that you're getting those warnings and would like to not get them?  Or is there something that should be happening in the actual document that isn't?

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I want the warnings to go away. The result already seems to be fine (it uses LM math).

Comment: @KhaledHosny: Why? `luatextra` claims "The luatextra package loads essential and useful packages for LuaLaTeX. It is meant as convenience for users who don’t want to load them individually."

Comment: @Martin: I see, my information was outdated (predating the introduction of `luatexbase`).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Regarding the first message, there is a beamer class option `professionalfont` which sets an `\if`, specifically `\ifbeamer@suppressreplacements` to decide whether beamer would handle some special font stuff or there was some other package to do it instead.  `unicode-math` checks to see if that `\if` has been set to true and if not, it issues the warning and then sets it to true.  So loading `unicode-math` ensures that that `\if` is set to true, but it might not be done as early as if you'd set the class option.

However, if you *do* set the class option, then you will get the warning:

> "professionalfont" is obsolete. Use font theme "professionalfonts" instead

There are two things to notice here.  First is that the class option is *not* `professionalfonts` (as `unicode-math` claims) but **`professionalfont`**.  Second, that it is obsolete.  Rather, you should issue the command:

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

somewhere in your preamble.  What *this* does is:

```
\mode<presentation>{\beamer@suppressreplacementstrue}
```

so it sets the same `\if` but **only** in *`presentation`* mode.  Thus it is ignored in `article` mode.  Since the `unicode-math` test only checks for the class being beamer, and not for the `beamerarticle` package, this is consistent.  Thus the correct preamble is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

Lastly, there *should* not be any actual problem if the middle line is missed since all it does is what `unicode-math` does when checking for the `beamer` class.  Thus the actual effect of the middle line is to suppress the warning with the `unicode-math` package.

(*Andrew now goes off and changes the preamble of his presentations because he'd been getting that warning with the `professionalfonts` class option and not understanding why he got it.*)

Comment: Thanks for a well written answer. And good luck changing your documents. :-)

Comment: For future reference: if you are using a beamer font style (e.g. serif), you still have to specify `\beamer@suppressreplacementstrue` manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[professionalfont]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iftex,ifxetex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{unicode-math} 
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=OldStyle}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
  \fi
\fi
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{(#1, #2)}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Speaker's Name}{About Our Next Speaker}
\LaTeX\ is good at typesetting mathematical formulas
like
       \( x-3y + z = 7 \) 
or
       \( a_{1} > x^{2n} + y^{2n} > x' \)
or  
       \( \ip{A}{B} = \sum_{i} a_{i} b_{i} \).

012345 $012345$ ff ffl ffi

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to get oldstyle numbers working with beamer.