# \dot{x} and beamer

Tags: beamer

Using `\dot{X}` with `beamer` ends up with an `x` with an omega on it!! 
My code:

```
\documentclass[15pt, slidestop]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae}

\usepackage{pgf,xcolor,pgfarrows,pgfnodes,pgfautomata,pgfheaps,pgfshade}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{bbm}   
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\frame{
  \frametitle{}

\begin{displaymath}
\dot{x}  =  A x(t) + B u(t)
\end{displaymath}

}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: Your example works on my machine (i.e. I get a dot, not an omega).

Comment: Same on mine (Mac OS X Lion, TeX Live 2012).  Could you pare down the list of packages to a minimal list that produces the error, and then say which version of each you are using (put `\listfiles` at the start of your document).

Comment: Just a remark: package `ae` is rather old and should not be used today (see [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu)).

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Mountain Lion, Tex Live 2012.Darwin xxxxx.local 12.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.1.0: Tue Aug 14 13:29:55 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.9.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: I have ommited the \usepackage{fourier} in my initial posting. The problem is with this package! Sorry guys, and thank you very very much for your advices.

Comment: If you really want to use the Fourier fonts for your presentation, then add the `professionalfont` option to `\documentclass`.

Comment: @egreg: No!  The class option is depreciated.  The font theme is the correct way to invoke this (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26829/86 for some details).

Comment: @AndrewStacey Well, the manual says to use the option with `fourier`, see p. 194.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beamer does some stuff internally with fonts.  If you load your own font package, you might want to switch that off.  The font theme `professionalfonts` is provided for this functionality.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\dot{x}  =  A x(t) + B u(t)
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: dot x with dot]