# Math symbols in beamer frame

Tags: beamer

I am trying to write a presentation with beamer. I have a problem with the symbol of "lim" as you can see in the attachment file. What is happening? Thank you in advance for your help.
My file is:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
         \usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
     \begin{document}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype} 
\setsansfont{Palatino Linotype} 
\setmonofont{Verdana} 
\setmathfont{Asana-Math}
\begin{frame}
 $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$,
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is with `lim`?

Comment: The code worked for me compiled with MikTeX-xelatex.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum. For example I can not compile it due to proprietary fonts. You should make it as simple as possible to us, to reproduce your error. And as short as possible: If you have a problem with the `\lim`, the MWE should read like `\documentclass{... \begin{document}\begin{frame}$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$\end{frame}\end{document}`

Comment: Term "lim" isn't dispayed.

Comment: When I have removed package unicode-math in combination with Asna -Math the problem with "\dipslaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} in resolved, that is lim is dispalyed, but I have lost some greek characters.

Answer (score 5):

The problem appears due to the use of `unicode-math` (deleting line by line and all the extra fonts showed this...).

You will have to put `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` to your preamble. For more information see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26829).

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}$
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]